# Why does my MVC 4 Project Partially Run on Production IIS 7 Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7

We have a ASP.NET MVC 4 project containing a number of controllers, models and views.

On our development server a Windows Standard 2008 (x64) the project is deployed/published and it runs fine.

However, when we try to publish the project to our live production server running a Windows Web 2008 x64 the MVC pages appear to partially load, but when we try to make calls to the controller it appears that it is failing.

It is very difficult for me to give more information, since I don't know where to trap the error or how to diagnose the problem.

Any help would be greatly received.

Comment: "appear to partially load"? Do you have a screen shot? Anything in the server Event Log (under Application)?

Comment: Are all required components (dlls) installed? Is there anything in the  event log?

Comment: Nothing in the Event Log, by partially loading I mean the page is loading, but when we try to make a ajax call to a Controller it appears to fail

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you targetting "any CPU" or "x86"? IIS needs "Enable 32-Bit Applications=True" (under app pool advanced settings). (DLLs are loaded on demand and it may be only that action that requires a 32 bit DLL which can't be loaded for that request)

Comment: @BradChristie It was set to False, I set it to true restarted the server and still have the same problem.

Comment: try to look at ajax response content with Fiddler, maybe it will say you something. Also enable custom errors to see what is happening

Comment: @KarelFrajtak How do you log everything ?

Comment: Log the exceptions, log what's going on - when controller action is invoked, what's the result, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of these depending on your .NET Framework version:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```